# Xamarin.IOS: localization does not work

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOS application and try to localize some images. 
As a guideline I took this article: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/

I try to display the image "ImageInstructionStep1"

Here is a screenshot of my Ressources Folder:

[image]

All images have the build action "BundleResource".
I assign the image in the code with this line:

```
        imageInstructionStep.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("ImageInstructionStep1");
```

And I registered the localizations in my Info.Plist:

```
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>de</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>it</string>
    </array>
```

But it always displays the english version.

I checked the locale the app has when I start it with this:

```
        NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
        NSLocale.AutoUpdatingCurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
```

and both give as a result "de_US". My expectations would have been that this would load the german localization.

Also I tried clean and rebuild the app to the simulator, including remove it from the simulator before without success.

Maybe interessting as a sidenote: all my  textes who are localized in resx file are shown in german as expected.

What do I miss?

Comment: You should put your fallback images into the Base folder.

Comment: aah greate. thanks. thought I can leave the fallback in the root.. Now I just have to figure out why my InfoPlist.strings is not applied. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I pointed out in the comments, you should put fallback resources into the `Base.lproj` folder.

As for your issue with `InfoPlist.strings`, keep in mind that they are applied only for strings in your `Info.plist`, so that is when you are asking for permissions etc. This could look as follows for `da.lproj`:

```
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Vil du tillade App'en til at bruge din lokation?";
"NSCalendarsUsageDescription" = "Ost";
```

and so on.

As for other strings, such as OK, Cancel and other buttons, you will need to add a `Localizable.strings` file for each folder with contents like:

```
"Back" = "Tilbage";
"Done" = "Færdig";
"Cancel" = "Anuller";
```