# Xamarin iOS - Load resources in any language without taking the language of the phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, localization

I have a Xamarin.IOS application and I try to load multiple permissions (like camera or gps) in different languages. I translate the text using InfoPlist.string inside the {lang}.Iproj.

I took this article: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization

How can I load a language without being caught by the language of the phone, if not one that I establish?

For example, if I set the default Spanish language in my application will load the texts but not the images. The application load en.Iproj instead of es.Iproj

[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56jBY.png)

I try this:

```
    var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("fr", "lproj");
    var languageBundle = NSBundle.FromPath(path);
    var myLocalizedString = languageBundle.LocalizedString("locloc", " ");
```

I try this:

```
    var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("en","lproj"); 
    NSBundle languageBundle = NSBundle.FromPath(path);
```

I read this and try: [Xamarin.IOS: localization does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205924/xamarin-ios-localization-does-not-work)

But nothing, I can not put the whole application in the same language

I use this example: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingResxLocalization/ but I added two features, I added a button to change the language and load the language that the user has chosen instead of the language of the phone.

I notified of changes in the system local by using the NSLocale.CurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification .... But nothing

Comment: I used this plugin and it's working fine.https://xamgirl.com/multilingual-localization-plugin-for-xamarin/

The only issue is that, for some reason, when I change the culture to another language, the page will not refresh directly. That is why I am opening a new page and let the user select the language , than redirect to the homepage or the page that the user was on.

Comment: Me too, I redirect to the homepage. But my problem is different, If you want the UI dialogs to be translated you must support the specific languages in your app you need to make this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/ but in my case is not working ... For example if your device is in English and your text in your app is in Spanish when you ask the permission like access to camera or something the text shown is based on the device of the phone and not the language of the app. I have InfoPList.strings and the folder.