# How can I get the current device language on iOS/Android?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I need to know what language is used on a iOS/Android device because I build a MonoGame application in Xamarin Studio that supports three different languages. If the current language of the device is english, than the app will show texts in english, but if the current language of the device is french, than the texts will get displayed in french instead of english. If the current language of the device is not supported in my application(for example chinese), than the default language for the texts will be english.

How can I get the current device language on iOS/Android in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.IOS: localization does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205924/xamarin-ios-localization-does-not-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the language programmatically, on Android you can use:

```
Locale.Default.GetDisplayLanguage(Locale.Default)
```

On iOS :

```
var userLang = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
```

Comment: It's not working. I get this error message for iOS: The name 'NSLocale' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)   And this error message for Android:  'Locale' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Comment: Make sure you have the correct usings for each. Both are public and available: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.Locale/  and  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSLocale/

Comment: If `Locale` is also defined in another namespace/assembly, you can fully qualify it" `Java.Util.Locale.Default.GetDisplayLanguage(Locale.Default)`

Comment: The return format of those two are very different though. `NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier` will return "en_US" and `Locale.Default.GetDisplayLanguage(Locale.Default)` will return "English"

Answer (score 6):

You could use CultureInfo:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```

Plus is cross-platform.